# Highcharts series data not persisting through angular route change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts with AngularJS. I have a directive which generates the chart. In the link function I specify a default object `chartOptions`. After setting the default options, I append that object to another object passed to the directive which persists between routes and refreshes, `passedObject`. Thus any changes to `chartOptions` after being appended successfully persist. Then the chart generates with the call to Highcharts.chart();

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        passedObject: "="
    },
    link: function (scope, element) {

        var chartOptions = {
            title : {
             text: 'sample report'
            }
            ...
        }

        scope.passedObject.chartOptions = scope.passedObject.chartOptions || chartOptions;

        var chart = Highcharts.chart(element[0], scope.passedObject.chartOptions);
    }

    // successfully add new series
    // series rendered immediately but does not persist though view changes and page reload.
    scope.addSeries = function(seriesObject){
        scope.elementObject.chart.addSeries(seriesObject);
    };

    // successfully pushes object to array
    // does not immediately render because Highchart doesn't see change 
    // but does render after reloading because Highchart checks options again
    // Does not render with animation like addSeries() API does.
    scope.addSeriesNoAPI = function(seriesObject){
       scope.elementObject.chart.series.push(seriesObject);
    };
}
```

There is no issue generating the chart the first time, and if I return to this view, the chart generates again with the same default options.

However, if I use the Highcharts API to programatically add a new data series `chart.addSeries(newSeriesObject)` the series is added and renders on the chart, but will not persist between routes and refreshes.

If I manually add the series object to my `chartOptions` via straight JS `scope.passedObject.chartOptions.series.push(newSeriesObject)` the object is successfully pushed to the array and will persist, but the chart will not automatically update because it doesn't know the `series` array changed, which is clearly why the API exists.

Upon closer inspection, it appears that Highchart's `addSeries()` function is pushing the new object to some array other than the one I am persisting, but I can't figure out how to get this to work.

I assumed that this line of code: `var chart = Highcharts.chart(element[0], scope.passedObject.chartOptions);` would bind the chart to the `scope.passedObject.chartOptions` object, such that when something like the `addSeries()` function added a new series, it would be added into `scope.passedObject.chartOptions`. After logging and watching objects, however that does not appear to be the case.

Comment: When you mean persist, are you talking about when switching between views?  Or do you mean when you reload the page?  Storing data on the rootScope or within a shared service can help you retain data between views, but won't help if a user refreshes the page.

Comment: I mean persisting of any kind, whether it be switching views or refreshing the page. But the issue is not persisting in general, the `passedObject` which I pass into the directive is stored in session storage and persists between switching views and refreshes, no issue. Also, changed made directly to that object persist without issue. The problem I think is how HighChart's `addSeries()` is pushing the new object, because its not pushing that object onto my options object and therefore is not persisting in either way.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to hold that data in the root scope (but that is not the best way).

Another is to use angular service to store this data. And include this service where you need it.

An angular service unlike controllers will not get reset when changing views/pages.

I would suggest that you create an angular service that stores the chart options, which has a chart options object and a getter and a setter. You could also hold the functions that make changes to the chartobject in this service.

In your case you seem to do manipulations to the chart object within the controller (after you are getting it from a service perhaps?), if so you will have to set the new object back to the service.

Also when I say service I mean something like this:

```
app.service('highChartService', function() {
  var chartOptions;
  var highChartServiceObj = {};

  highChartServiceObj.getChartOptions = function() {
      return chartOptions;
  };

  highChartServiceObj.setChartOptions = function (options) {
     chartOptions = options;
  };

  highChartServiceObj.computeChartObject = function () {
    //do some computation
  }

  return highChartServiceObj;

});
```

Add the above service to your directive and use that to update your highchart object when any changes are made.

Also if I am not wrong what you would like to do is add newseriesobject like this `chart.addSeries(newSeriesObject)` which solves your highchart dilemma. Why not then update your chart object as the next step: `scope.passedObject.chartOptions.series.push(newSeriesObject)`? Though I would rather that be part of the service too if I was doing this, all of the highchart manipulations would just be a part of the service, where I would have a function like this in above service:

```
highChartServiceObj.updateChart(newSeriesObject, chart) {
   chartOptions.series.push(newSeriesObject);
   chart.addSeries(newSeriesObject);
}
```

Comment: The problem is not with persisting data in general, the problem is with how Highcharts is adding the new series object to the chart. I added more text to the end of my post to clarify. The options object is persisted in a service, but Highcharts doesn't appear to be pushing the new data series into the array specified in the generating of the chart.

Comment: I can't make sense of it completely with just the code you have provided, but it looks like you are manipulating the chart object data within the controller, which would make it out of sync with which ever service you got the data from. If you are using a service, then any changes to the object obtained from the service should also be done within the service or else set back to the service on change.

Comment: I added two functions to show what I mean. If I add the new series object via the Highchart api function, it will not persist beyond views and page reloads. If I add the object by manually pushing it onto the array, it will not immediately render, but will render if you reload the chart, and will persist, but does not have the fancy loading animation that the Highchart API does.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some steps, which might work, which does mean you need to do the two steps you explained consecutively, but should work. Which is do the highchart api bit and update the object after the fact to the scope.